# I get following error when trying to generate a pdf using php by making use of html2fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf, html2pdf

```
Warning: include(font/helvetica.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\fpdf.php on line 541

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'font/helvetica.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\fpdf.php on line 541
FPDF error: Could not include font metric file
```

please help.

Comment: Seems like a pretty straightforward error message...

Comment: Have you checked if folder `C:\xampp\php\PEAR\font` contains file `helvetica.php`?

Comment: there is no such folder named C:\xampp\php\PEAR\font , but there is a file helvetica.php in folder C:\xampp\php\PEAR\fpdf\font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to configure that in one of the php files - I remember vaguely coming into that issue. There's a CONSTANT variable with a path to fonts folder. Check for it in the main php file.

Or you could just create that directory and copy the font into that directory.

Comment: just opened the fpdf.php - go to line 105  ... you can define before that line with this:  define('FPDF_FONTPATH','YOURPATH');

Comment: thanks, issue resolved, but again I get this error ...


Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\html2fpdf\html2fpdf\html2fpdf.php on line 506


Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\html2fpdf\html2fpdf\html2fpdf.php on line 383

Comment: *chuckle* I had that issue as well.. it's quite an old script. You just replace that with preg_match().

Comment: good day... i put this before line 105 define('FPDF_FONTPATH','C:\xampp\htdocs\fmsystempanamed\file\chtmltopdf\font');  is this ok?